# I don't have access to the Apple ID acct on my iPad and the login icons keep poppin up. What can I do

Tags: ios-appstore

I can't access the Apple ID acct on my device. The device was given to me and she never told me the password and I can't ask her. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, do NOT do a factory reset, because if the device ever needs activating it will **require** the password. This is to deter thievery.

You need to turn off the iCloud integration, and switch all the IDs to be yours. I believe that to do this you will need the password for the current ID, so you really should go to your friend and get her to type the password in for you.

Again - this is to stop people from stealing iPads/iPhones, as they are effectively unusable without the password.

Comment: I don't have a way to contact her. I got to the point of resetting it but now I need access to her email acct to retrieve it! Lol

Comment: Oh dear. You are now the proud owner of a very attractive slab of glass and aluminium ... but it won't be an iPad again until she logs on to it and turns off iCloud. Sorry ...

Comment: Uggghhhh! I think I wanna cry like a baby and throw a fit! Thanks for helpin!

Comment: No worries - if you want to help back, please accept this answer. Thanks! And sorry about your iPad ... harsh.